# Identity in ASP.Net Core 2.1< - Customize AccountController

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

I have installed `ASP.NET Core 2.1` but even though I have created a new `ASP.NET Core Web Application` using `ASP.NET Core 2.1` with `Individual User Accounts` → `Store user accounts in-app` I can't find the AccountController or Views.

I can still register and login without a problem but I can't find the code for it, it were present in 2.0.

[image]

Comment: I have asked a question here if you are interested in answering: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51728881/how-do-i-use-identity-server-with-net-core-2-1.  I am struggling with logout in a .NET Core 2.1 Identity Server 4 app.  +1.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

One of the [changes in 2.1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-2-1-0-now-available/) was Razor Class Libraries and the default identity lives in one of these in the individual auth templates. If you would like to have the code in your app so you can customise it, you can scaffold it out with Visual Studio, or with the global scaffolder tool. See [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio) on how to do both.

Comment: I was able to generate cshtml files not controllers. Guide didn't mention it, any idea how to generate accountController?

Comment: Ah my bad.. its like designer in subfile

Comment: why is this thing an *improvement*? It makes things unnecessarily convoluted.

Answer (score 98):

ASP.NET Core 2.1 introduced new feature called Razor class libraries that lets you build views and pages as part of reusable library. ASP.NET Core Identity was moved to such RCL. You can override it in your project:

1. From **Solution Explorer**, right-click on the project > **Add** > **New Scaffolded Item**.
2. From the left pane of the **Add Scaffold** dialog, select **Identity** > **ADD**.
3. In the **ADD Identity** dialog, choose files you wish to override.

   1. Select layout if necessary
   2. Select or create **Data context class**.
4. Hit **ADD**.

For more information [visit documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: You need to right click on the project not the solution to get the 'New Scaffolded Item' .. Thanks for the heads up on this

Comment: This still does not bring in the Account Controller field say i have added customized fields how do i tell it I need them in the register method.

Comment: Hey what if I want to overwrite the controller instead of the razor page? I'm using SPA so i'm not sure if i can override the controller

Comment: an accepted answer was already acepted no need to say now @WibisonoIndrawan

Answer (score 7):

My solution is create project with .net core 2.0, and then update the framework to 2.1 and all the dependence to latest version

Answer (score 4):

Turns out `ASP.NET Core Identity` is now available as a prebuilt package called `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI`.

You can read more about it here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/03/02/aspnetcore-2-1-identity-ui/

Answer (score 3):

Since `ASP.NET Core 2.1` the [identity UI is shipped as a library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI).

But you can override the views and controllers by placing them at the right locations (e.g. View/Account/Login.cshtml).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware, the AccountController code has been moved to Razor pages (and their code behinds) and works best using defaults so to customise the code you can Scaffold (ie create the files in the right place) from a brand new Net Core 2.1 project by right-clicking the Project in Visual Studio 2017 and seleting Add => New Scaffolded Item => Identity which opens a Select Dialog. Choose desired pages and there you go. Just change the pages you want and copy to same place in an Identity enabled project as these new pages automatically override the defaults. This is the new way to customize authentication/authorization using Identity not sure whether many consider this significant progress!