# Where is the identity view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

When I create a new project in .NET Core 2.1, I can not find the views behind /Identity/Account/Manage? Where is it, how do I change the page style now?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identity in ASP.Net Core 2.1 : Customize AccountController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50676654/identity-in-asp-net-core-2-1-customize-accountcontroller)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The views are now part of a precompiled library ([Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI)) being linked into the project, not separate pages. You can create the views yourself and they will override the library ones if needed.

For more information see the [Microsoft blog post.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/03/02/aspnetcore-2-1-identity-ui/)

You can also [scaffold the identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio) into the project.