# Can't find the account pages in Asp.Net Core 2.1

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core

I've created a brand new site from Visual Studio, and selected "Individual User Account" authentication.  The page `_LoginPartial.cshtml` contains the following:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
    <li><a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a></li>
</ul>
```

The site works, and allows me to navigate to the `Register` and `Account` pages; however, I can't see those pages in my project.  I don't have, for example, a `/Account/Register.cshtml`.  My assumption is that the line at the top of `_LoginPartial`:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
```

Has something to do with this; but what?

Are these pages hosted remotely (F12 doesn't seem to be telling me I'm leaving the site), are they baked in but hidden in some way, have I just missed them (if so, sorry!)?

Comment: 2.1 introduced the ability to embed views in external DLLs, I'm guessing the templates do this now.

Comment: `ASP.NET Core 2.1 and later provides ASP.NET Core Identity as a Razor Class Library. `  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50802781/where-are-the-login-and-register-pages-in-an-aspnet-core-scafolded-app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the identity view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51016785/where-is-the-identity-view)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASP.NET Core 2.1 introduced the ability to [embed views in external class libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio), and the templates are using this feature. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio) for more information on how this works specifically with ASP.NET Core Identity and how to override the embedded views.

Comment: This might be the subject of a separate question, but how would you use DI with these libraries?