# No AccountController for asp.net core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I realise in asp.net core 2.1 Identity has been shifted, but can be added to the solution if you add them as a scaffolded item.

It adds all the razor class library for all the pages.

However what I want to do is have the old AccountController way where a client (mobile or web) can post to the account related API's..

What are my options for being able to get the old way back or similar. so that i can use api's from clients

Comment: Can this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50676654/identity-in-asp-net-core-2-1-customize-accountcontroller

Comment: @SehaxX, Yes realise that, but i dont have any API's to work with that can be used by clients. Seems like it only works with web?

Comment: Have you tried this compatibility version where are links probably also for login: services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.AllowAreas = true;
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Identity", "/Account/Manage");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Identity", "/Account/Logout");
        });

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, it doesn't exist any more. I was personally very aggravated by this change, as well as the team's endless pushing of Razor Pages on everyone, which frankly should have been left in the dustbin of history `</rant>`.

What I have done, personally, is add the scaffold, and then create my own controllers, shuffling and rewriting the Razor Pages code into traditional MVC-style controllers and views. This was *not* a pleasant experience, though, but I know of no other way if you want it this way.

One thing to note, though, is that the `AddDefaultIdentity` extension actually adds the default UI, as well, just as if you had scaffolded it into your project. In other words, even if you move everything over to controllers and views and delete all the scaffolded stuff, the Razor Pages routes will *still* take precedence. Even more unfortunate, there's no *good* alternative to add `AddDefaultIdentity`. This is what you'll need instead:

```cs
services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(o =>
{
    // Identity config
})
.AddSignInManager()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<YourContext>();

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(o =>
{
    o.LoginPath = "/signin";
    o.LogoutPath = "/signout";
    o.AccessDeniedPath = "/signin";
    o.ReturnUrlParameter = "returnUrl";
});
```

Obviously, in the last bit, you'd change the URLs to your own applications routes.