# How do you modify the "Register User" method in dotnet core EF 5.0

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, .net-core

When a new user registers, I need to create a folder etc. I want to find a Controller for this. Note - I have already inherited from IdentityUser as described in:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0

How can I do this in dotnet core EF 5.0 rc1?

Answer (score 0):

1. Find your Register User Method(Usually Controllers>AccountController>Register)
2. Modify it

If you selected Individual User Accounts but your project doesn't containg Account controller.You need to add it manually.For razor view.You can Right Click your project> Add > New Scaffold Item and select Identity then check your required pages you want to add.

Comment: I did this, I now have many .cshtml files in Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage, one IdentityHostingStartup.cs in Areas/Identity but no IdentityController in Controllers.

Comment: What is the type of your project?

Comment: MVC, dotnet core 5.0 EF. I have a class for a user's default UI navigation and what it should contain. I wish to populate it as the User registers.

Comment: You can find user register code inside Register.cshtml.cs(when expand Register.cshtml) method is OnPostAsync. If you want old controller you need to add it on your own... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51138449/no-accountcontroller-for-asp-net-core-2-1