# How do I use Identity Server with .NET Core 2.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am trying to get Identity Server working on an ASP.NET Core 2.1 project and I have followed the instructions [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html), however, I realize those are for ASP.NET Core 2.0.

The Startup in the MVC client looks like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
    .AddCookie("Cookies")
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
        options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.ClientId = "mvc";
        options.ClientSecret = "secret";
        options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.Scope.Add("api1");
        options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
    });
```

With ASP.NET Core 2.1 the identity component is accessed here: `http://localhost/Identity/Account/Login`.  The code above is redirecting to: `http://localhost/Account/Login`.  My first idea was to replace the following line:

```
options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
```

with:

```
options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000/Identity";
```

However, I then get an error saying:

> IOException: IDX10804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'http://localhost:5000/Identity/.well-known/openid-configuration'.".

This is because the path needs to be: 'http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration'.

Can I fix this with routing? I believe if I ensure all requests to: `http://localhost:5000/Account/Login` are mapped to `http://localhost:5000/Identity/Account/Login`, then it will fix the issue.  Is this correct and what would the route look like? I cannot get the route to work with an Area (Identity).

Comment: You seem to be mixing up things here: The identity server and your web application should be separate server applications. Only the former will have a login URL. – If the IdSrv is on `localhost:5000`, then that should be the authority you need to configure on the web application. The login redirect will happen on the IdSrv application though and *that* is where you configure the login URL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you are using OpenID Connect, you are *not* having a login form on the web application. You are delegating the login responsibility to the OpenID Connect provider. In your case, that is IdentityServer, which is running in a separate application.

As such, it is not your web application you need to configure here: The authority *is* the root URL of your IdentityServer, so `"http://localhost:5000"` should be correct there. What you need to configure instead is IdentityServer to make it redirect to the right endpoints if it receives authorization requests without the user being logged in.

You can do that in the `Startup` of your IdentityServer application, where you add the service:

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/Identity/Account/Login";
    options.UserInteraction.LogoutUrl = "/Identity/Account/Logout";
})
```

Comment: Thanks.  That works.  +1.  The problem now is that Identity Server does not redirect back to the client app after authenticating.  Is there anything else I have to do? Are there any Quuickstarts that show how to get Identity Server working with .Net Core 2.1?

Comment: If it’s not redirecting back, then your login form apparently does not redirect back to the `returnUrl` after completing the authentication. And yes, there are quickstarts because the ones for 2.0 work just the same in 2.1. Nothing has changed in that regard.

Comment: Is there anything I can check? I am completely stuck.

Comment: The problem is your login form. Check that you are passing on return URLs properly. Check the ASP.NET Core Identity templates in doubt to see how they handle it.

Comment: Thanks.  I have started from scratch and it is actually because the authentication process is not working.  If I add the following code then I cannot login: services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
        .AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
        .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
        .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
        .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
        .AddAspNetIdentity<IdentityUser>();

Comment: There is a problem with the last line.

Comment: There’s [a tutorial for integrating ASP.NET Identity](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html). You can follow that, even if you use 2.1. It’s still the same stuff you need to do.

Comment: I have followed this tutorial three times now.  For a start the ApplicationUser class does not exist (so I created it).  Do you know what this error means: "No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' has been registered.".

Comment: Then your project does not have Identity set up properly. See [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity) for more information. You need to make that work _first_ before adding IdentityServer.

Comment: I have just followed the instructions in your link immediately above step by step (for .net core 2.1).  Step two causes a compilation error: "The type or namespace ApplicationUser cannot be found".  The instructions work perfectly for .NET Core 2.0.

Comment: Have you tried creating a core 2.1 project that uses Identity?  Sorry for all of the questions, however I cannot believe how difficult this is.

Comment: Use `IdentityUser` instead of `ApplicationUser` in the quickstart. The `ApplicationUser` assumes that you have your own user type that inherits from `IdentityUser`.

Comment: I have figured out how to do this now.  One more thing before I accept.  The Logout hyperlink simply opens the Logout page (then the user clicks logout again).  How can I ensure the user is logged out the first time? +1 by the way.

Comment: You can call `HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookie")` to force a sign-out at any time. It’s possible that your logout link puts that behind a form submit to prevent GET requests from randomly logging the user out.

Comment: Are you able top have a look at my other Identity Server question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56872070/using-identity-server-inside-an-xamarin-app

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it helps but I had trouble with the Net Core 2.1 Identity implementation (The Login/Logout pages do not always appear) and needed to add a default Identity as follows in Startup.cs

```
   // Identity Context
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["DefaultConnection"],
                                sqlOptions => sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().
                                Assembly.GetName().Name));
        },
            ServiceLifetime.Scoped
        );

        // Configure default Identity implementation
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultUI()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

The previous version (Net Core 2.0) is currently end of life (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/06/20/net-core-2-0-will-reach-end-of-life-on-september-1-2018/) so would not expect to find many GitHub repositories hosting applications that months on still only compile, build, and work using Net Core 2.0. IdentityServer is currently the only Open Source application providing a satisfactory best practice authentication/authorization framework for Single Sign On (SSO) using Open ID Connect and OAuth2 ;-)