# ASP.NET Core Identity Model Customization Select List

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm new to asp.net core (using Core 2.1) and am trying to customize the identity model. I've figured out how to add custom fields, like `FirstName`. However, I'm stuck on trying to add a select list to the model for use in registration. The contents of the list should come from another table in the database. I've extended the user model so that the database has a one-to-many relationship with the other table, but I'm not sure how to populate the registration form with the contents of the other table and get the selected value into the user table. I've found direction on how to do this with a regular controller, but not how to incorporate it with the identity model.

The specific scenario is that when users register they need to identify a level (eg. Junior, Senior, etc.) that determines options they see within the application.

My User model is:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ApplicationUser() : base() { }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Level Level { get; set; }
}
```

My Level model is:

```
public class Level
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string LevelName { get; set; }

    public string LevelDescription { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I'm just not sure where to go with `Register.cshtml.cs` and `Register.cshtml`, or if there is some other way I should be thinking about this.

I've tried adding level to the `InputModel`, but I don't know how to actually populate the list or grab the id for my user model.

```
public int LevelId { get; set; }
public ICollection<SelectListItem> Levels { get; set; }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So your goal is to send list of levels to registration page, allow user to select level and send value back to server?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want the user to pick from the list of levels when they register.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I finally figured this out. This question got me on the right track: [Identity in ASP.Net Core 2.1 : Customize AccountController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50676654/identity-in-asp-net-core-2-1-customize-accountcontroller).

The key to my issue was that, unlike MVC, the controller for the razor page is the code behind, in this case, Register.cshtml.cs. Most of the following is in that file.

First I added a reference to the database so I could get to the Levels table. I added the 3 lines that say "context" to the default file to make the database available.

```
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
    private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public RegisterModel(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
        ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
        IEmailSender emailSender,
        ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
        _emailSender = emailSender;
        _context = context;
    }
```

Next I added a property to the model view to hold the Levels (in the same section as Input and ReturnUrl).

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Levels { get; set; }
```

Inside InputModel, I only have the LevelId because I moved Levels out to the model.

```
    public class InputModel
    {
     ...
     public int LevelId { get; set; }
     ...
    }
```

I added to the OnGet method to actually populate the model before it goes to the view.

```
    public void OnGet(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ReturnUrl = returnUrl;

        // collect all levels from database
        List<Level> availableLevels = _context.Levels.ToList();
        // convert to selectlistitems
        Levels = availableLevels.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.LevelName, Value = x.Id.ToString() }).ToList();
    }
```

OnPostAsync needs to know what to do with the selected level, otherwise it won't make it into the database.

```
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = Input.Email,
                Email = Input.Email,
                Level = _context.Levels.Where(x => x.Id == Input.LevelId).FirstOrDefault()
            };
            ...
```

Finally, in Register.cshtml I added this tag to display the level in the view.

```
       <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Input.LevelId"></label>
            <select asp-for="Input.LevelId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Levels, "Value", "Text"))" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Pick One</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="Input.LevelId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

Everything seems to be working as intended now.