# CS0029 C# Cannot implicitly convert type to 'int?' ASP.NET CORE 5 MVC Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET Core 5 MVC Identity. I want to customise the registration and adding a selection list from another table, that user can decide to choose an option or not.
So I'm following the answer from this
[ASP.NET Core Identity Model Customization Select List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55190931/asp-net-core-identity-model-customization-select-list)

but I countered a problem. I did pretty much the same.

User Model

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser

        [ForeignKey("GameID")]
        public int? GameID { get; set; }
```

game model

```
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string GameName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
```

Register.cshtml.cs

```
private readonly ApplicationDBContext _context
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GameList { get; set; }

RegisterModel{}()part
ApplicationDBContext context
_context = context;
```

```
InputModel
public int? GameID { get; set; }

OnGetAsync
GameList = availableLevels.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.GameName, Value = x.ID.ToString() }).ToList();

OnPostAsync
GameID = _context.Games.Where(x => x.ID == Input.GameID)
```

I don't have experience posting stuff and I'm a noob at coding. Hope it makes sense

Comment: Why is your `int` nullable (the `?` after `int`)?

Comment: Also do you have a full stack trace? That will tell you what line is causing the error

Comment: This doesn't make sense: `GameID = _context.Games.Where(x => x.ID == Input.GameID)`  You're trying to store a *list of Games* as a single `int?` value.  A list of games is a lot more data than just an integer.  Which is what the error is telling you, your collection of game objects can't be converted to an `int?`.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: are you just trying to get a single game id? if so GameID = _context.Games.Where(x => x.ID == Input.GameID) this is where the issue is

Comment: this code looks *nothing* like the code in the question you posted a link to;  that code isn't asynchronus, doesn't have an `InputModel`, doesn't use a nullable int (`int?`);  overall, this code isn't useful to understanding your problem at all.

Comment: @MenachemHornbacher the reason is nullable is because the user doesn't have to input data for that field. is optional

Comment: @Raven so why is it tied to their user account? should it not be stored in a separate place?

Can a user only have one game? Are games intrinsically tied to users?

Comment: I think we need to know more about your data model to understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this
in your register.cshtml

```
in OnGetAsync

GameList = _context.model name in your DBcontext.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.yourgames???.ToString(), Value = x.ID.ToString() }).ToList();
```

and on your OnPostAsync keep it simple

```
GameID = Input.GameID
```

In razor remove that select line from that link and change it to

```
<select asp-for="Input.GameID" asp-items="Model.GameList" class="form-control">
```

I don't know how the person on the link does it, but in the context of that link and the post is about the selection in register form I beleive.